# How to keep track of time in JSP page

Tags: jsp, time, jsessionid

I have a JSP page that takes input from the user and when the user presses SAVE the data goes to a server along with a JSESSION ID which is use to authenticate the user.The JSessionID expiers after 10 mins of inactivity.

Now it may happen that user presses the save button after 10 min.In that case the JSESSIONID would expire and server would throw an exception, which would be visibe to the user

What i want is to fire dummy query to server after every 9 mins so that the Jsessionid does not expire..Now how do i keep the track of time in my JSP page..

Comment: With a timer? Why not just make your session ID timeout value longer? Working *around* session timeout seems a bit odd; don't you have it set to a relatively-low 10 minutes for a *reason*? How about instead doing something *reasonable* when their session times out rather than showing them an exception?!

Comment: @DaveNewton, one difference would be that the sessions would expire after ten minutes if the browser window is closed, instead of the longer time period.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard Yep, obviously.

Comment: @DaveNewton :This is not me who has set the timeout 10 mins.Its the Oracle.i am working on CRMOD Integration with other technologies.I just want some code that can tell 9 mins have passed so that i can fire a dummy query and the JSessionID remains active....

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to make an AJAX call to your server after a timeout.

For instance, assuming you're using jQuery:

```
window.setInterval(
  function () { $.get('ping.jsp'); },
  9*60*1000);
```

Documentation:

- [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)
- [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

If you aren't using jQuery, you'll have to replace the `$.get` call with browser-spefic code or code from another library.

Alternatively, you could use a [Meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) or `Refresh` header, but as noted in that article there are a number of good reasons not to.  However, in an invisible `iframe` it might not be so bad.  I'd still go with the JavaScript version myself.

Comment: ok..What If i want to call a servlet say "myservlet" (this servlet fires dummy query) and also pass some data stored in the variable "sessid" ...How would I use it using your sufggestion.Also if i want to use Jquery, would copy-paste your code will work or i need to write or include something else also

Comment: @Sankalp, you would have to replace 'ping.jsp' with the path of your servlet.  If you click on the link for the jQuery.get documentation it explains how to pass data.  You will need to include something else also.